# Information retrieval evaluation of precision, recall, f-score, AP, MAP in Python

Tags: python, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I wrote one program to perform information retrieval.
User enters a query in the search bar, the program can show the relevant text result such as the relevant sentence and the article which consists of the sentence.

I did some research for how to evaluate the result. I might need to calculate the `precision, recall, AP, MAP...`

How to calculate the result?

> Since my dataset is not labeled and I did not do the classification. The dataset I used was the article from BBC news. there were 200 articles. I named it as `001.txt, 002.txt ... 200.txt`

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do the evaluation in python. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Since you are new, i am writing briefly how to compute precision, recall, fscore, AP and MAP in an information retrieval system.

**Precision and Recall**

Precision measures "of all the documents we retrieved as relevant how many are actually relevant?".

```
Precision = No. of relevant documents retrieved / No. of total documents retrieved
```

Recall measures "Of all the actual relevant documents how many did we retrieve as relevant?".

```
Recall = No. of relevant documents retrieved / No. of total relevant documents
```

Suppose, when a query "q" is submitted to an information retrieval system (ex., search engine) having 100 relevant documents w.r.t. the query "q", the system retrieves 68 documents out of total collection of 600 documents. Out of 68 retrieved documents, 40 documents were relevant. So, in this case:

`Precision = 40 / 68 = 58.8%` and `Recall = 40 / 100 = 40%`

F-Score / F-measure is the weighted harmonic mean of precision and recall. The traditional F-measure or balanced F-score is:

```
F-Score = 2 * Precision * Recall / Precision + Recall
```

**Average Precision**

You can think of it this way: you type something in `Google` and it shows you 10 results. It’s probably best if all of them were relevant. If only some are relevant, say five of them, then it’s much better if the relevant ones are shown first. It would be bad if first five were irrelevant and good ones only started from sixth, wouldn’t it? AP score reflects this.

Giving an example below:

[image]

> AvgPrec of the two rankings:

Ranking#1: `(1.0 + 0.67 + 0.75 + 0.8 + 0.83 + 0.6) / 6 = 0.78`

Ranking#2: `(0.5 + 0.4 + 0.5 + 0.57 + 0.56 + 0.6) / 6 = 0.52`

**Mean Average Precision (MAP)**

MAP is mean of average precision across multiple queries/rankings. Giving an example for illustration.

[image]

> Mean average precision for the two queries:

For query 1, `AvgPrec: (1.0+0.67+0.5+0.44+0.5) / 5 = 0.62`

For query 2, `AvgPrec: (0.5+0.4+0.43) / 3 = 0.44`

So, MAP = `(0.62 + 0.44) / 2 = 0.53`

Sometimes, people use `precision@k`, `recall@k` as performance measure of a retrieval system. To do experiment, you can use the well-known dataset of [AOL Search Query Logs](http://www.researchpipeline.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=AOL_Search_Query_Logs) to build a retrieval-based system (you just need a retrieval function in addition) and then do experiment with that. I am giving one example of document ranking function.

**Document Ranking / Retrieval Function**

**Okapi BM25** (BM stands for Best Matching) is a ranking function used by search engines to rank matching documents according to their relevance to a given search query. It is based on the probabilistic retrieval framework. BM25 is a [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) retrieval function that ranks a set of documents based on the query terms appearing in each document, regardless of the inter-relationship between the query terms within a document (e.g., their relative proximity). See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) page for more details.

Comment: Great answer! Would you be able to extend it to explain how to plot a PR curve in the context of CIBR? I've never seen a nice simple explanation of the algorithm to do that, i.e. what threshold is varied in this setting to make the plot's points?

Comment: I have a similar question to yours @M.R.. I've been wondering how I plot a Precision-Recall curve that represents an entire set of queries, instead of a single query. Should I take, for example, the mean (between all queries) of the precision and recall values at different points, and plot that?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation has two essentials. First one is a test resource with the ranking of documents or their relevancy tag (relevant or not-relevant) for specific queries, which is made with an experiment (like user click, etc. and is mostly used when you have a running IR system), or made through crowd-sourcing. The second essential part of evaluation is which formula to use for evaluating an IR system with the test collection. 
So based on what you said, if you don't have a labeled test collection you cant evaluate your system.